# jQuery.post() is calling both GET and POST

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, post, get

I have a simple asp.net mvc app with [HttpPost] controller methods defined. For some reason when calling jQuery.post() 2 requests are posted to the server:

1. http GET which returns 404 and then
2. http POST which returns successfully.

Can anyone explain why the initial GET request? This generates loads of useless errors.

Sample code:

```
<a href="~/group/create/" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GroupModal">Create Group</a>
<script>
$('#GroupModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var _this = $(this);
        var _btn = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var _body = _this.find('.modal-body');
        $.post(_btn.attr('href')).done(function (r) { _body.html(r); });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe you should show us some code. My guess, you are cancelling the action that is triggering the Ajax call.

Comment: I may be wrong, but if I recall correctly, the first GET request is actually a OPTIONS request, as it tries to determine the server capabilities in order to correctly submit the POST request

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and CODE. The get could be from the form you forget to cancel `$("#formId").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $.post....`

Comment: @Melanef not if it's a same-origin request.

Comment: The only thing in your question that does a GET request is the anchor tag itself if the default action isn't prevented.

Comment: @Melanef I was thinking the same thing (options request). Is there any way to turn off that functionality?

Comment: @KevinB Could it be that Bootstrap modal is making GET ajax call based on href value?

Comment: could be, dunno. is it supposed to be? (docs are available)

Answer (score 1):

By default Bootstrap 3 makes a remote ajax GET request to href value. Issue solved by add data-remote="false" to anchor.